# Can I further vectorize this function

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I am relatively new to R, and matrix-based scripting languages in general. I have written this function to return the index's of each row which has a content similar to any another row's content. It is a primitive form of spam reduction that I am developing.

```
if (!require("RecordLinkage")) install.packages("RecordLinkage")

library("RecordLinkage")

# Takes a column of strings, returns a list of index's
check_similarity <- function(x) {
  threshold <- 0.8
  values <- NULL
  for(i in 1:length(x)) {
    values <- c(values, which(jarowinkler(x[i], x[-i]) > threshold))
  }
  return(values)
}
```

is there a way that I could write this to avoid the for loop entirely?

Comment: @akrun updated, cheers

Comment: @d.b no, I am comparing against all other rows, x[i], x[-i]

Comment: Maybe try this: `m = as.matrix(sapply(x, jarowinkler, x)) > threshold; diag(m) = 0; which(rowSums(m)>0)` No reproducible data for me to test on, but I think this works.

Comment: @dww that works really well, and is exactly what I wanted, cheers. If you answer the question I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Just as a note, the main inefficiency in your code isn't that you *have* a `for` loop, it's that your *growing a vector* inside the for loop. See [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/) for extended discussion. `sapply` gets around that nicely: it will put the values in a pre-allocated `list` and then simplify it for you, but efficiency-wise you could do just about as well modifying your for loop.

Comment: Just as a 2nd note. if you were to improve the for loop as @Gregor suggests, be careful about a subtle bug in the way you have it now. Your `for` loop is returning the index position in a vector that excludes the value you are comparing to. I.e. it is finding the positions in `x[-i]` which is not the same as positions in `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simplify the code somewhat using `sapply`.

```
# some test data #
x = c('hello', 'hollow', 'cat', 'turtle', 'bottle', 'xxx')

# create an x by x matrix specifying which strings are alike 
m = sapply(x, jarowinkler, x) > threshold

# set diagonal to FALSE: we're not interested in strings being identical to themselves
diag(m) = FALSE

# And find index positions of all strings that are similar to at least one other string
which(rowSums(m) > 0)
# [1] 1 2 4 5
```

I.e. this returns the index positions of 'hello', 'hollow', 'turtle', and 'bottle' as being similar to another string

If you prefer, you can use colSums instead of rowSums to get a named vector, but this could be messy if the strings are long:

```
which(colSums(m) > 0)
# hello hollow turtle bottle 
#     1      2      4      5
```